# The Death Of An Angel

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, story, poetry

> Lovely she was, oh the things I wanted to do to her...
>
> Going to that nice restaurant, eating everything I could and even
>   more.
>
> Giving her that ring was hard, I desired to keep it  for myself so bad.
>
> She was full of energy but after a while, I became tired and it was
>   getting boring for both of us.
>
> "Who the hell is that!" I shouted after I struck her soft cheek.
>
> Everything was a lie, there was someone better than I.
>
> Pain wasn't necessary, but unlike me, she was weak and deserved it...

**Oh God, what did I do wrong?**

HINT 1

> The answer has something to do with Christianity.

Comment: Wtf, thats creepy..

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and guess it's something to do with atoms, but you should seek professional help.

Comment: @FrancescoRoggia Puzzles with a creepy twist, awesome right?

Comment: Yeah,very unusual I must admit. @MvW. Btw, when you use "she" do you mean that it has a female gender ? #YouKnowWhatIMean

Comment: @SwarnabjaBhaumik If this isn't one of those "assume gender" jokes, yes, By "She" I mean the female gender. :)

Comment: And how many times are we going to see these sins? :-)  Though, the riddle makes sense now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**My guess is:**

> The Seven Deadly Sins (Fullmetal Alchemist for the win)

Lovely she was, oh the things I wanted to do to her...

> **Lust** (Sexual cravings)

Going to that nice restaurant, eating everything I could and even more.

> **Gluttony** (Over-indulging esspecially by over eating)

Giving her that ring was hard, I desired to keep it for myself so bad.

> **Greed** (Desire to keep material things for yourself)

She was full of energy but after a while, I became tired and it was getting boring for both of us.

> **Sloth** (Laziness and lack of effort)

"Who the hell is that!" I shouted after I struck her soft cheek.

> **Wrath** (Uncontrolled feelings of hatred and anger)

Everything was a lie, there was someone better than I.

> **Envy** (Jealousy of another persons happiness)

Pain wasn't necessary, but unlike me, she was weak and deserved it...

> **Pride** (Inflated sense of one's self)

Comment: I'd love to +1 this, but the existence of the subject of your guess far predates the reference you added to it.

Comment: Haha, no I'm personally a Christian and was able to piece it together, as fate would have it Fullmetal alchemist is my favorite and I hoped people would appreciate the reference.

Comment: Nice, good job! Was it to easy?

Comment: Nah, I puzzled over it a bit, just took the correct line if thought.